# Gulp Jscs - TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: gulp, gulp-jscs

I wanted to use gulp-jscs in my project, so I've installed it according the [documentation](https://github.com/jscs-dev/gulp-jscs):

```
npm install --save-dev gulp-jscs
```

But when I try to run the gulp file, I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.keys (native)
    at copyConfiguration (C:\Users\[User]\Desktop\[Project]\
    node_modules\jscs\lib\config\configuration.js:920:12)
```

Also, there are other errors related to this:

```
at NodeConfiguration.Configuration.
_processConfig([location-path]\node_modules\jscs\lib\config\configuration.js:459:5)
    at NodeConfiguration.Configuration.load 
([location-path]\node_modules\jscs\lib\config\configuration.js:211:10)
    at null.StringChecker.configure 
([location-path]\node_modules\jscs\lib\string-checker.js:62:29)
    at null.Checker.configure ([location-path]\node_modules\jscs\lib\checker.js:27:39)
    at Object.module.exports ([location-path]\node_modules\gulp-jscs\index.js:35:10)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> ([location-path]\Gulpfile.js:60:17)
    at module.exports ([location-path]\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:34:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask ([location-path]\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:273:3)
Process terminated with code 1.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to have a `.jscsrc` file in the root of you project present. In there you can provide [options for JSCS](http://jscs.info/overview#options) as well as [the code style rules](http://jscs.info/rules.html) that should be followed.

Below is the `.jscsrc` that's [used by `node-jscs` project itself](https://github.com/jscs-dev/node-jscs/blob/master/.jscsrc). You can use this to base your own configuration on.

```
{
    "preset": "google",
    "fileExtensions": [".js", "jscs"],

    "requireSemicolons": true,
    "requireParenthesesAroundIIFE": true,
    "maximumLineLength": 120,
    "validateLineBreaks": "LF",
    "validateIndentation": 4,
    "disallowTrailingComma": true,
    "disallowUnusedParams": true,

    "disallowSpacesInsideObjectBrackets": null,
    "disallowImplicitTypeConversion": ["string"],

    "safeContextKeyword": "_this",

    "jsDoc": {
        "checkAnnotations": "closurecompiler",
        "checkParamNames": true,
        "requireParamTypes": true,
        "checkRedundantParams": true,
        "checkReturnTypes": true,
        "checkRedundantReturns": true,
        "requireReturnTypes": true,
        "checkTypes": "capitalizedNativeCase",
        "checkRedundantAccess": true,
        "requireNewlineAfterDescription": true
    },

    "excludeFiles": [
        "test/data/**",
        "patterns/*"
    ]
}
```

Note that `jscs` won't actually check for anything unless you have a `"preset"` in your `.jscsrc` or have explicitly specified the [rules](http://jscs.info/rules.html) that should be followed.