# Gulp Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: node.js, gulp

my `gulpfile.js` contains the ff:

```
'use strict'

// All add-ons required
const gulp = require('gulp')
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify')
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps')
const csso = require('gulp-csso')
const htmlmin = require('gulp-htmlmin')
const concat = require('gulp-concat')
const rename = require('gulp-rename')
const del = require('del')

// Tasks

// Minifies HTML
gulp.task('pages', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/*.html')
    .pipe(htmlmin({ collapseWhitespace: true, ignoreCustomComments: '[ /!/ ]', removeComments: true }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'))
})

// Copy NPM frameworks to vendor/
gulp.task('vendor', function() {
  return gulp.src(['./node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css', './node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js'], { base: 'node_modules' })
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/vendor/'))
})

// Minifies CSS
gulp.task('styles', function() {
  return gulp.src('./src/assets/styles/*.css')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
  // Minify the file
    .pipe(csso())
  // Concatenate all CSS files to 'styles.min.css' then Output
    .pipe(concat('design'))
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min.css' }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css/'))
})

// Minifies JS Files
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  return gulp.src('./src/assets/js/*.js')
  // Create a sourcemap
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
  // Minify the file
    .pipe(uglify())
  // Concatenate all js files to 'app.min.js' then Output
    .pipe(concat('asset'))
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min.js' }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js/'))
})

// Minifies the main Renderer file `main.js`
gulp.task('renderer', function() {
  return gulp.src('./src/main.js')
  // Create a sourcemap
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
  // Minify the file
    .pipe(uglify())
  // Concatenate all js files to 'app.min.js' then Output
    .pipe(concat('app'))
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min.js' }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'))
})

// Cleans the dist/ folder if not empty
// to avoid conflicts per gulp runs
gulp.task('clean', function() {
  return gulp.src('dist/*')
    .pipe(del('./dist/*'))
})

// Default Build
gulp.task('default',
  gulp.series('clean', gulp.parallel('pages', 'vendor', 'styles', 'scripts', 'renderer')))
```

everytime I run `gulp` or `gulp [task]` it just throw some errors that didn't make sense for me:

```
[19:43:57] Using gulpfile ~\Desktop\LAN\Workspace\Code\secret [revamp]\gulpfile.js
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\lib\taskTree.js:4
  return Object.keys(tasks)
                ^

TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\lib\taskTree.js:4:17)
    at logTasks (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:134:14)
    at C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:127:14
    at internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:70:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:47:5)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:763:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:303:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:872:3)
```

Already tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40773304/gulp-jscs-typeerror-cannot-convert-undefined-or-null-to-object) but unluckily didn't work out for me.

**P.S** 
my `gulp` version is `"gulp": "^4.0.0"`

Comment: Joshua i am facing the same issue with gulp 4.0.0. were you able to resolve it later or it still exists?

Comment: *probably* because of the gulp version, try 3.x.x. unfortunately the project was stopped/abandoned for reason that's why I didn't find the solution to it.

Answer (score 1):

Was facing the same issues and found out this probably has to do with Settings made in your IDE, for example PHPStorm. In my case PHPStorm was using Gulp 3.7 interpreter instead of the local 4.0 which is installed by NPM.

Go to Run » Edit configurations » Gulp